# Submit multiple files in axios request as an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, file-upload, axios

I have to send multiple images as part of an API call in a format

```
{
"date":"currentDate",
"files":[Files uploaded via input box]
}
```

I used the following approach for the same

1. **Approach 1**

   ```js
   const event = document.querySelector("#files");
   const filesData = new FormData();
   filesData.append(`files`, event.files);
   filesData.append("date", "2021-04-07");
   ```

Form Data in browser coming:

> files: [object FileList]
> date: 2021-04-07

2. **Approach 2**

   ```js
   const filesData = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < event.files.length; i++) {
       filesData.append(`file${i}`, event.files[i]);
       }

   formData.append("date", "2021-04-07");
   ```

Form Data in browser coming:

> file0: (binary)
> file1: (binary)
> file2: (binary)
> file3: (binary)
> date: 2021-04-07

2. **Approach 3**

   ```js
   const filesData = new FormData();     
   filesData.append(`files`, Object.values(event.files));
   formData.append("date", "2021-04-07");
   ```

Form Data in browser coming:

> files: [object File],[object File],[object File],[object File]
> date: 2021-04-07

It is relatively easy in POSTMAN.
[image: POSTMAN call]

**Can somebody guide about a proper way to acheive the same, as API is failing**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was researching and looking for the solutions, I got to know an interesting feature in Postman where one can see the **Code Snippet** of the axios call.

On the top right corner of Postman, there is

- **</>** symbol in v8+
- Alongside Cookies **Code** for before versions

This opens up Code snippet wherein you can see code snippet corresponding to axios request in different languages.

**Solution:**

```
const event = document.querySelector("#files");
const filesData = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < event.files.length; i++) {
  filesData.append(`images`, event.files[i]);
}
filesData.append("date", "2021-04-07");
```

Hope this helps many others just like me.